# bootstrap button.js set state from database value

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the button.js from twitter bootstrap 3.x to toggle buttons in a form. How do I set a button to a value from a database?

Ex. if value for options in database is set to Option1. How do I toggle that button to the active state? I use the next code to check a button in normal html, but how to set it with the jquery/bootstrap buttons?

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" <?php if ($options == 1) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" <?php if ($options == 2) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" <?php if ($options == 3) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>> Option 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Edit:

Eventueally it is solved by using

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary  <?php if ($options == 1) { echo 'active'; } ?>">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" <?php if ($options == 1) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary  <?php if ($options == 2) { echo 'active'; } ?>">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" <?php if ($options == 2) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary  <?php if ($options == 3) { echo 'active'; } ?>">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" <?php if ($options == 3) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>> Option 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pure php and html. I want to use http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons. So I need, when the php variable from the database (or if the form is posted and shown because there are problems) is for example $options=1, that the jquery button is set to active.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fs9az/4/ here the yes/no are both not activated. How do I get one activated on load?